# How to hide a ajax Request from Web Browser's Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

The Browser's web console Network Tab shows all the ajax request with the server response. How Can I prevent ? is it possible to do ?

The reason is because the ajax response shows all the users data, that's why I'm trying to hide the response.

Comment: May I ask you: Why? It is the whole purpose of this tab. If you don't want it keep it closed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this???

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Because the ajax response shows all the users data..thats y i'm tried to hide the response

Comment: So you are sending data into the world and are concerned that somebody could read it? That's the way it works, you cannot prevent this.

Comment: You cannot hide an ajax response, you should HTTPS if you dont want it seen, but even HTTPS is visible on the local network with suitable software

Comment: what is possible to do about this

Comment: Why are you trying to hide *the user's data* from *the user*? It's their data. They should be able to see it.

Comment: If you are sending something to the browser in an Ajax request, it is supposed to be visible and manipulable client-side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible and even if it was, it would be an undesirable "solution" because the data can be seen using other methods.

The solution is to revise your code to ensure you only send data to the user that they are authorised to see. Don't dump all user data in the AJAX response.

Comment: Please Tell about Jsonp Call in ajax request

Comment: @user1422892 you can't do anything about that, and even if you could, it would not change anything at all. It's not because the request doesn't appear in the network tab that the request is not visible "elsewhere". When you open a web page, your browser knows it, your OS knows it, your internet service provider knows it, your proxy provider knows it, the web server you're talking to knows it, the NSA knows it too ! You can't avoid all of this just by "hiding" the request in the network panel

Comment: The benefit of hiding it, however, would be for performance. As the console grows for a single page application, it can get incredibly slow. Sure, optimizing your ajax requests would take care of this, but take a gis application into account. Each time a tile or group of tiles is requested, those requests appear in the console. The need for muting this for performance I think is warranted to some degree.